# Generating n binary vectors where each vector has a Hamming distance of d from every other vector

Tags: python, algorithm, encryption, vector, cryptography

I'm trying to generate `n` binary vectors of some arbitrary length `l`, where each vector `i` has a Hamming distance of `d` (where `d` is even) from *every other* vector `j`. I'm not sure if there are any theoretical relationships between `n`, `l`, and `d`, but I'm wondering if there are any implementations for this task. My current implementation is shown below. Sometimes I am successful, other times the code hangs, which indicates either a) it's not possible to find `n` such vectors given `l` and `d`, or b) the search takes a long time especially for large values of `l`.

My questions are:

- Are there any efficient implementations of this task?
- What kind of theoretical relationships exist between `n`, `l`, and `d`?

  ```
  import numpy as np

  def get_bin(n):
      return ''.join([str(np.random.randint(0, 2)) for _ in range(n)])

  def hamming(s1, s2):
      return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(s1, s2))

  def generate_codebook(n, num_codes, d):    
      codebooks = []
      seen = []

      while len(codebooks) < num_codes:
          code = get_bin(n)
          if code in seen:
              continue
          else:
              if len(codebooks) == 0:
                  codebooks.append(code)
                  print len(codebooks), code
              else:
                  if all(map(lambda x: int(hamming(code, x)) == d, codebooks)):
                      codebooks.append(code)
                      print len(codebooks), code
              seen.append(code)

      codebook_vectorized = map(lambda x: map(lambda b: int(b), x), codebooks)
      return np.array(codebook_vectorized)
  ```

Example:

```
codebook = generate_codebook(4,3,2)
codebook

1 1111
2 1001
3 0101
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Good question, please see the edits

Comment: if _d_ is odd, then _n_ is at most 2 (you can't have 3 values all with different parities in the number of 1s)

Comment: @qwertyman updated the question to qualify *d*

Comment: The problem of finding sets of sequences with a minimum hamming distance (as opposed to a fixed hamming distance) is well-studied but inconclusive. In particular, the maximum size of the set for given minimum distance and sequence length is only known for small and trivial parameter values. I suspect that your version of the problem is not simpler.

Comment: @rici I think this problem is about finding sets of sequence with an _exact_ Hamming distance, rather than a minimum, but maybe the OP can clarify that.

Comment: @jdehesa: I know, and I said that (in parentheses). But, as I said, I don't think OP's problem is simpler, and the difficulty of the minimum-distance problem is indicative. (In addition, I don't really see the practical benefit of exact-distance sets. It's an interesting math question which might be better asked on [math.se]. But perhaps there is one.)

Comment: I suspect this question is more of a coding theory question (and thus a math question) than a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

Let's build a graph `G` where every `L`-bit binary vector `v` is a vertex. And there is an edge `(vi, vj)` only when a Hamming distance between `vi` and `vj` is equal to `d`. Now we need to find a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) of size `n` is this graph.

> Clique is a subset of vertices of an undirected graph such that every
>   two distinct vertices in the clique are adjacent.

The task of finding a clique of given size in an arbitrary graph is NP-complete. You can read about this problem and some algorithms in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Cliques_of_fixed_size).

There are many [special cases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Special_classes_of_graphs) of this problem. For example, for [perfect graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph) there is a [polynomial algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_graph#Algorithms_on_perfect_graphs). Don't know if it is possible to show that our graph is one of these special cases.

Comment: This is an interesting approach to the problem, but it discards information that probably makes it easier to solve.

Comment: @jdehesa, graph is just a different representation of the data. Of course, our graph is not an arbitrary, but I can't prove that it belongs to one of the special cases https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Special_classes_of_graphs, maybe someone can.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real solution, but more of a partial discussion about the relationship between `l`, `d` and `n` and the process of generating vectors. In any case, you may consider posting the question (or a similar one, in more formal terms) to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com). I have been reasoning as I was writing, but I hope I didn't make a mistake.

Let's say we have `l = 6`. Since the Hamming distance depends only on position-wise differences, you can decide to start by putting one first arbitrary vector in your set (if there are solutions, some may not include it, but at least one should). So let's begin with an initial `v1 = 000000`. Now, if `d = 1` then obviously `n` can only be 1 or 2 (with `111111`). If `d = 1`, you will find that `n` can also only be 1 or 2; for example, you could add `000001`, but any other possible vector will have a distance of 2 or more with at least one the vectors you have.

Let's say `d = 4`. You need to change 4 positions and keep the other 2, so you have 4-[combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) from a 6-element set, which is 15 choices, `001111`, `010111`, etc. - you can see now that the binomial coefficient `C(n, d)` plus 1 is an upper bound for `n`. Let's pick `v2 = 001111`, and say that the kept positions are `T = [1, 2]` and the changed ones are `S = [3, 4, 5, 6]`. Now to go on, we could consider making changes to `v2`; however, in order to keep the right distances we must follow these rules:

- We must make 4 changes to `v2`.
- If we change a position in a position in `S`, we must make another change in a position in `T` (and viceversa). Otherwise, the distance to `v1` would not be kept.

Logically, if `d` were odd you would be done now (only sets of two elements could be formed), but fortunately you already said that your distance numbers are even. So we divide our number by two, which is 2, and need to pick 2 elements from `S`, `C(4, 2) = 6`, and 2 elements from `T`, `C(2, 2) = 1`, giving us `6 * 1 = 6` options - you should note now that `C(d, d/2) * C(l - d, d/2) + 2` is a new, lower upper bound for `n`, if `d` is even. Let's pick `v3 = 111100`. `v3` has now *four* kinds of positions: positions that have changed with respect to both `v1` and `v2`, `P1 = [1, 2]`, positions that have not changed with respect to either `v1` or `v2`, `P2 = []` (none in this case), positions that have changed with respect to `v1` but not with respect to `v2`, `P3 = [3, 4]`, and positions that have changed with respect to `v2` but not with respect to `v1`, `P4 = [5, 6]`. Same deal, we need 4 changes, but now each change we make to a `P1` position must imply a change in a `P2` position, and each change we make to a `P3` position must imply a change in a `P4` position. The only remaining option is `v4 = 110011`, and that would be it, the maximum `n` would be 4.

So, thinking about the problem from a combinatoric point of view, after each change you will have an exponentially increasing number of "types of positions" (2 after the first change, 4 after the second, 8, 16...) defined in terms of whether they are equal or not in each of the previously added vectors, and these can be arranged in couples through a "symmetry" or "complement" relationship. On each step, you can (I think, and this is the part of this reasoning that I am less sure about) greedily choose a set of changes from these couples and compute the sizes of the "types of positions" for the next step. If this is all correct, you should be able to write an algorithm based on this to generate and/or count the possible sets of vectors for some particular `l` and `d` and `n` if given.